# How to AUTO SELECT saved data to select option chain dropdown AJAX in form EDIT?

Tags: php, ajax

i cant load data to edit dropdown menu chain from saved data with AJAX

all tutorial i tried search just about input chain dropdown menu autoselect AJAX to input, i need to show saved data in form EDIT

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
$(document).ready(function() { 
    $("#provinsi").append('<option value="">Pilih</option>'); 
    $("#kabupaten").html(''); 
    $("#kecamatan").html(''); 
    $("#kelurahan").html(''); 
    $("#kabupaten").append('<option value="">Pilih</option>'); 
    $("#kecamatan").append('<option value="">Pilih</option>'); 
    $("#kelurahan").append('<option value="">Pilih</option>'); 
    url = 'ajax/get_provinsi.php'; 
    $.ajax({ url: 
        url, 
        type: 'GET', 
        dataType: 'json', 
        success: function(result) { 
            for (var i = 0; i < result.length; i++) 
            $("#provinsi").append('<option value="' + result[i].id_prov + '">' + result[i].nama + '</option>'); 
        } 
    }); 
}); 
$("#provinsi").change(function(){ 
    var id_prov = $("#provinsi").val(); 
    var url = 'ajax/get_kabupaten.php?id_prov=' + id_prov; 
    $("#kabupaten").html(''); $("#kecamatan").html(''); 
    $("#kelurahan").html(''); $("#kabupaten").append('<option value="18">Pilih</option>'); 
    $("#kecamatan").append('<option value="">Pilih</option>'); 
    $("#kelurahan").append('<option value="">Pilih</option>'); 
    $.ajax({ 
        url : url, 
        type: 'GET', 
        dataType : 'json', 
        success : function(result){ 
            for(var i = 0; i < result.length; i++) 
            $("#kabupaten").append('<option value="'+ result[i].id_kab +'">' + result[i].nama + '</option>'); 
        } 
    });  
}); 
$("#kabupaten").change(function(){ 
    var id_kab = $("#kabupaten").val(); 
    var url = 'ajax/get_kecamatan.php?id_kab=' + id_kab; 
    $("#kecamatan").html(''); $("#kelurahan").html(''); 
    $("#kecamatan").append('<option value="">Pilih</option>'); 
    $("#kelurahan").append('<option value="">Pilih</option>'); 
    $.ajax({ 
        url : url, 
        type: 'GET', 
        dataType : 'json', 
        success : function(result){ 
            for(var i = 0; i < result.length; i++) 
            $("#kecamatan").append('<option value="'+ result[i].id_kec +'">' + result[i].nama + '</option>'); 
        } 
    });  
}); 
$("#kecamatan").change(function(){ 
    var id_kec = $("#kecamatan").val(); 
    var url = 'ajax/get_kelurahan.php?id_kec=' + id_kec; $("#kelurahan").html(''); 
    $("#kelurahan").append('<option value="">Pilih</option>'); 
    $.ajax({ 
        url : url, 
        type: 'GET', 
        dataType : 'json', 
        success : function(result){ 
            for(var i = 0; i < result.length; i++) 
            $("#kelurahan").append('<option value="'+ result[i].id_kel +'">' + result[i].nama + '</option>'); 
        } 
    });  
}); 
</script>
```

i want to make dorpdown chained (selected) automaticly to view same dato from save before